# Reading and writing with cordova-plugin-file working when debugging on intel xdk, but not after building

Tags: android, file, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

So I am trying to store a JSON file with different app stats on an android app developed in Intel XDK. I am running the app through the debugger and I can store and read the files. However, once the app is built and I install the APK on my device, I cant see nothing. Looks like the file is never stored.

I am using the dataDirectory as can be seen in the following line.

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) {
dir.getFile("hiscore.json", {create:true}, function(file)

Anyone any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: If the outcome is changed by adding breakpoints in a step-through debugger, it's possibly a concurrency issue where interruption of execution by the debugger is altering the order of async operations. Try adding console.log statements at each breakpoint and run without interruption

Comment: I have log statements and do not use any breakpoints. Everything works fine when i run or debug the app through the intel app preview on my device  by using the intel xdk debugger tab. The app stores nothing when it is built.